# RequireJS sugar for main require

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My javascript file starts with a configuration...

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        'code-mirror': 'codemirror/main',
        'esprima': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/esprima/1.2/esprima',
        'jquery': 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min',
    },
})
```

...and then requires...

```
require( ['jquery', 'code-mirror', 'profile', 'feedback', 'browser-detect'], function($, CodeMirror, undefined, feedback, browser){
```

...and it works!  Now, I attempted to use the sugar syntax instead, like so...

```
require( function(require){

var $ = require('jquery'),
    CodeMirror = require('code-mirror'),
    undefined = require('profile'), // functions bound to window
    feedback = require('feedback'),
    browser = require('browser-detect');
```

...and it does NOT work!  Why?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CommonJS sugar syntax is available only for `define`, not for `require`.

If you look at the source code of RequireJS, look for the regular expression named `cjsRequireRegExp`. This is the regular expression that is used to deal with the CommonJS syntax. Search for its occurrences: you'll see it used only for `define`.